# google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2:1 : '%%writefile {model_pipline}': Expected identifier or number, got %

Tags: python, tensorflow, config

the below is the error I faced,
the **training code** I used is:

```
!python3 /content/model_main.py \
--pipeline_config_path=/content/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config \
--model_dir=training/
```

**error:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/model_main.py", line 109, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/content/model_main.py", line 71, in main
    FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples))
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 617, in create_estimator_and_inputs
    pipeline_config_path, config_override=config_override)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 104, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 693, in Merge
    allow_unknown_field=allow_unknown_field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 760, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 785, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 807, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 875, in _MergeField
    name = tokenizer.ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1343, in ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber
    raise self.ParseError('Expected identifier or number, got %s.' % result)
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2:1 : '%%writefile {model_pipline}': Expected identifier or number, got %.
```

**my config coding:**

```
%%writefile object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config


model {



ssd {
    num_classes: 14 # number of classes to be detected
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_ca

lculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    # all images will be resized to the below W x H.
    image_resizer { 
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        #use_dropout: false
        use_dropout: true # to counter over fitting. you can also try tweaking its probability below
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
            # weight: 0.00004
            weight: 0.001 # higher regularizition to counter overfitting
          }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            # weight: 0.00004
            weight: 0.001 # higher regularizition to counter overfitting
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000 
        iou_threshold: 0.95
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6

        #adjust this to the max number of objects per class. 
        # ex, in my case, i have one pistol in most of the images.
        # . there are some images with more than one up to 16.
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        # max number of detections among all classes. I have 1 class only so
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 16 # training batch size
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.003
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }

  #the path to the pretrained model. 
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/models/research/pretrained_model/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000 


  #data augmentaion is done here, you can remove or add more.
  # They will help the model generalize but the training time will increase greatly by using more data augmentation.
  # Check this link to add more image augmentation: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_contrast {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    #path to the training TFRecord
    input_path: "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/data/train_labels.record"
  }
  #path to the label map 
  label_map_path: "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/data/label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  # the number of images in your "testing" data (was 600 but we removed one above :) )
  num_examples: 6
  # the number of images to disply in Tensorboard while training
  num_visualizations: 20

  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  #max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {

    #path to the testing TFRecord
    input_path: "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/data/test_labels.record"
  }
  #path to the label map 
  label_map_path: "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/data/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Someone please help me! I face this error when running training code, I dont know where is going wrong, is it the problem of the quotations mark? How should I fix it?
the model_main.py and config file are uploaded in colab, i faced the problem also when i mount to gdrive but for now is temporary solved. Actually I just want to post this error, but system want me to add some more details, so can ignore these sentences. I am newbie in this field, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, please check [this git issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1897) which offer many answers.

I solved it by editing the `pipeline.config` file with the ubuntu built-in text editor instead of LibreOffice. LibreOffice changed the format from `*.config` to (I guess) `*.conig.txt`

Other solutions in the Git issue are:

- Correctly setting quotation marks ('...' or "...")on your path declarations
- Putting all labels into the label.pbtxt
- Removing spaces between lines in label.pbtxt
- Removing the comments on top of the pipeline.record file
- Possible linebreak problem
- checked my label files with small Linux command-line program "file", to find

> ```
>  broken.pbtxt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
>  working.pbtxt: ASCII text
> ```